# Why does set iterator pointer cause segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault, set

Bottom line, why would iterator cause segmentation fault? 
Note, I'm **typing** here the relevant parts of my code and not copy pasting. If there is an error in compilation, please note but do not consider it the source of my issue.

In my code, I have a map of boxes for beads:
    `map<vector<int>,set<shared_ptr<bead> > > > nextBoxes;`

Each bead has, among others, a `vec pos` member which, in turn has:

```
  class vec{
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
  .
  .
  .
  vector<int> getBox();
  .
  .
  .
}

vector<int> vec::getBox(){
  vector<int> out(3,0);
  extern double boxSize;
  out[0] = x/boxSize;
  out[1] = y/boxSize;
  out[2] = z/boxSize;
  return out;
}
```

I use a very simple method to get through the beads into the boxes

```
extern vectrot<shared_ptr<bead> > beads;
for (int i = 0; i < beads.size(); i++){
  vector<int> t = beads[i]->pos.getBox();
  nextBoxes[t].insert(beads[i]);
}
```

Elsewhere in the code, the `pos` values of the beads might change and I update the boxes locally.

I use the following loop to go through the boxes and beads:

```
map<vector<int>,set<shared_ptr<bead> > >::iterator mit = nextBoxes.begin();
extarn vector<vector<int> >::targets; //holds a vector of a 1, -1 and 0 vectors of distance from the box
extern int boxNum;
while (mit != nextBoxes.end()){
  vector<int> t1 = mit->second();
  set<shared_ptr<bead> >::iterator bit1 = mit->second.begin();
  set<shared_ptr<bead> >::iterator bit2;
  while (bit1 != mit->second.end()){ 
    shared_ptr<bead> b = *bit++;
    vector<int> t2(3,0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 13 i++){//13 is the size of the targets index.
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        t2[j] = t1[j] + targets[i][j];
        if (t2[j] >= boxNum) t2[j] -= boxNum;
        if (t2[j] < 0 ) t2[j] += boxNum;
      }
      bit2 = beadsBoxes[t2].begin();
      while (bit2 != nextBoxes[t2].end()){
        shared_ptr<bead> b2 = *bit2++//the segmentation fault is here
        .
        .
        .
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason, I get a segmentation fault. What I got so far is:

- the segmentation fault is cause because of the incrementation of the interator.
- the box size is 2.
- this is not the first box I am testing (didn't count them but it runs for a while).
- I have absolutely no idea how to access the second element in the box (the first I can use the iterator since I don't increment it.
- This is the outPut error from gdb:

  0  0x00002aaaaab43c65 in std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
  1  0x000000000041a28e in operator++ (this=0x63d7c0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_tree.h:265

I'll appreciate any help, thanks.

**Edit:** 
Solved, kinda.

Trying to reduce the error to a minimum running example, I have deleted all those line and rewritten them and now things look fine. I'm still interested of such a case though:

If you want, I can reask the question:
*When will iterator incremental cause a segmentation fault in c++?*

Comment: "If there is an error in compilation, please note but do not consider it the source of my issue. " - If the code you've shown us doesn't compile, we have no way of guessing what the *real* issue is.

Comment: I don't see a declaration of `bit2`, nor a declaration of `beadsBoxes`, so I really can't say why the indicated line is faulting. Please reduce your program to its simplest form that still displays the problem, and **copy-paste** that program into your question. In the process of reducing your program, you may discover the bug on your own. For more information about this reduction-and-pasting technique, and why it is important, see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @jalf, the idea is that it is not an error of compilation to begin with

Comment: @Rob: I wish I could reduce it, I don't know, yet the reason for this and I  am afraid that it is originated from something which is immanent in c++ that I don't understand yet. I was hoping that this is some well known issue with iterators.

Comment: @Yotam: but my point is that if you show us code that doesn't work, and tell us to ignore the things that make it not work, then it is impossible for us to tell you why it doesn't work! If you want a useful answer, you need to show us code where the *only* problem is the one you want help with.

Comment: @jalf: comments such as Rob's where he state the ``beadsBoxes`` is not declared are relevant. I'm speaking (writing actually) about comments such as forgotten ``;`` or unclosed brackets.

Comment: @Yotam: excuse me, but **you** are the one asking others for help. That means that **you** do not understand why your code behaves like it does. And that means that **you** are not the one deciding what is or is not relevant. If you knew what was relevant, you'd have solved the problem already yourself. The people who are trying to answer your question are the ones who decide what is relevant.

Comment: @jalf: anything that I will say now will only make you even more mad. I'm sorry I have upset you. I was only trying to stress a point....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your edit the only way possible:

> If you want, I can reask the question: When will iterator incremental cause a segmentation fault in c++?

Incrementing an iterator will cause a segmentation fault only if it is used incorrectly.

That's it.

The standard doesn't list the cases in which code must segfault, it only lists what should happen when code is used *correctly*. When you use it *incorrectly*, it is simply undefined behavior, and any of a million things might happen, including, but not limited to, segmentation faults.

If incrementing your iterator gave you a segfault, it is either because:

- the iterator already pointed to the end of the set, or
- the iterator pointed outside the set, to a variable that had gone out of scope, or perhaps the iterator had never been initialized at all.

But segmentation faults happen when you have undefined behavior. And that, by definition, makes it impossible to tell you which cases will trigger a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3):

At least one error is present in these lines:

```
  bit2 = beadsBoxes[t2].begin();
  while (bit2 != nextBoxes[t2].end()){
    shared_ptr<bead> b2 = *bit2++//the segmentation fault is here
```

Assuming `beadsBoxes` and `nextBoxes` are objects of standard container types, you are using the iterator incorrectly.

`bit2` appears to be an iterator pointing at the members of `beadsBoxes`. But, you are comparing it to the end of `nextBoxes`. If `beadsBoxes[2]` and `nextBoxes[2]` represent different objects, you can't do that.

Comment: You are correct but. 1. This error does not appear in my code (to my knowledge). 2. This error will produce a segmentation fault when I try to access bit2 and not increment it...

Comment: 1) It appears in your code, as posted in the question. I can't comment on any other code. 2) Depending upon the implementation of `bit2`, the fault may very well occur in `operator++` and not in `operator*`.

Comment: As for 1 you are correct, I only state that it doesn't appear in my code. As for 2, can you give me an example for that case? I'm asking this because that with my experience, I'v only  encountered what I have stated. (My experience is mainly in scientific programming so I'm not counting this as a real experience).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should fix is `getBox`. It does not return a value, so undefined behavior happens when it is called. Add `return out;` at the end.

Comment: Good point, fixed. I wonder, what will happen in that case? I think that the code would not compile